# Advice on downgrading Solution from .NETframework 4.6.2 to .NetFramework 4.5.2

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

Hey I have read a lot of posts about upgrading frameworks, but unfortunately I'm in a situation where I need to downgrade my solutions framework. I have 15 projects inside the solution and I have switched the targeted framework each individually to 4.5.2 inside the properties.
I have used inside Nuget Package Manager Console to try and reinstall the packages based off the new targeted framework. 
    `Update-package -reinstall`

One of my main obstacles is when I rebuild my project it wont create any ddl's in my `/bin/debug` folder. 
I also still get a bunch of errors about entity restSharp being too high of a version for the target framework.

I have tried searching fixes through stack overflow and google and everything that i have tried hasn't worked yet.

Please help give some advice or considerations.

I am using VS enterprise 2015, on windows 10

Comment: Try uninstalling restSharp nuget packages, then also under References for each project remove any restSharp related references(sometimes devs add these using browse and uninstalling the nuget package won't remove the reference).  Do a Clean, then reinstall old version of restSharp nuget packages.  Also, it won't produce bin/debug assemblies because you have compile time errors.  It is possible Nuget gallery doesn't have old enough version of restSharp targeting your framework version, and you may have to obtain it elsewhere.

Comment: Your .DLLs are not getting generated because it can't compile due to restSharp being the wrong version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downgraded my project target framework to 4.6.1 to 4.5 . Because .net framework 4.6.1 requires a Windows update.

To re-install RestSharp package :

- Uninstall RestSharp
- Install RestSharp **105.0.0**